# python decrement at special case in for-loop

Tags: python, loops

I need to decrement in a python for-loop at a special case (or just don't increment).

In C-like languages, this can be easily accomplished by decrementing the index, or if you have an iterator-like structure you could just "decrement" the iterator. But I have no clue how to achieve this in python.

One solution would be to create a while loop and increment manually, but that would, in my case, bring in lots of extra cases, where just one case is needed when I could decrement.

###### C Example

```c
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    if (some_condition) {
        i--;
    }
}
```

###### Python equivalent

```py
for i in range(0, N):
    if some_condition:
        i -= 1        # need something like this
        i = i.prev()  # or like this
```

Comment: This looks like an xy-Problem to me. How does the loop continue after that? `i` will never get past `X` in both examples.

Comment: @schwobaseggl good catch, but what do you mean by XY problem?

Comment: @suvayu See [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/357835).

Comment: @schwobaseggl in the second example, `i = X-1` will be repeated twice, after which the loop will skip to `X+1`. I agree that OP needs to clarify just what sort of looping behavior they are trying to achieve.

Comment: @JohnColeman I'd argue that depends on whether the actual loop body comes before or after this mingling. But you are right, the python for loop will move on.

Comment: Indeed @schwobaseggl, but only when you interpret the problem as an arithmetic problem. But it would be much more reasonable (and also the case) that the condition would be a logic condition based on IO or other things. X doesn't have to be a number or the condition doesn't need to depend on i (I'm going to correct that).

Comment: You are still quite vague about what you are trying to do, but using a `while` loop seems like the obvious solution. It isn't clear why you are trying to use a `for` loop here. You could perhaps make a custom generator and use a `for` loop to iterate over that, but I suspect that the resulting code would be less readable than a simple `while` loop.

Comment: @john-coleman I want to improve readability by decrementing the iterator, but as this is not possible (without writing a lot more code and therefore making things more unreadable) I appreciate it if you could post ~that comment as a post and I will accept that.

Answer (score 0):

You can make an iteration loop by yourself. You could easily add a loop index independent from `next` calls, so that you could even use a skip condition that uses the current index.

```
skip_iteration = True
it = iter(range(10))
iterating = True
value = next(it)
while iterating:
    try:
        print(value, end=' ')
        if skip_iteration:
            # iteration skip code
            skip_iteration = False
        else:
            # normal iteration code
            value = next(it)
    except StopIteration:
        iterating = False
```

Here only the first iteration is skipped, which outputs :

```
0 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

This code relies on the fact that the `next` function raises `StopIteration` if it reaches the end of the iterator.

Answer (score -1):

If the condition in the `if` statement is somehow related to the iterator `i` itself then the loop might not end but if the condition is not depended on `i` then there shall not be any problem

you can also try skipping that particular iteration by using `continue`.